# Check if page parent has certain template

Tags: php, functions, filters, hooks

I want to check if a page has a parent with a certain page template attached to it.

If I know that I can determine which scripts to load or not.
Normally I would just get the page template and if it is a match load the scripts needed but now I have the script in my `functions.php` file and can't get the `$page->ID` to check.

I don't really know how to solve this.
In my `functions.php`:

```
require_once('js/my_script.php');
```

`my_script.php`:

```
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'function_name');
function functions_name( $myhtml ) {
    //do stuff
};
```

This hooks into an existing function. I can't check within the function because that would disable the complete function if the statement would be false.

Comment: i would rather edit the page template in question to include the scripts...

Comment: But this is in the admin meta-box of the page so the template wouldn't be able to affect this right?

Comment: not sure what you exactly mean. you certainly can write php code and enqueue scripts in page templates

Comment: Yes I know but the script I wrote is used in the admin page. It has effect on the featured-image panel. If I understand you correctly it should be possible to add this code to the template and let the code be executed if the template is assigned to a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered on Stack Overflow before:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14626254/844732

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'check_page_template' );
function check_page_template() {
    global $post;
    if ( 'page-homepage.php' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ) ) {
        // The current page has the foobar template assigned
        // do something

    }
}
```